# Problem using rangelength for jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-validate, range, validation

I'm using the jQuery Validator Plugin. My code is like this:

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="newtextbox required" rangelength="(4,16)">
```

The error message is "Please enter a value between NaN and 4 characters long". The actual error message that has to be is "Please enter a value between 4 and 16 characters long".

I think the HTML I have used is incorrect.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using square brackets instead:

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="newtextbox required" rangelength="[4,16]">
```

Still, you shouldn’t be defining this inside the HTML; you can do this with JavaScript.

```
$("#some-form").validate({
 rules: {
  field: {
   required: true,
   rangelength: [4, 16]
  }
 }
});
```

You can [read more about the rangelength method of the jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/rangelength) if you wish.

Comment: Thank you Mathias. I am using jquery.validator.js. There is already a option to use rangelength for the validation but the problem is how to use this in html. Hope you get what i mean. Thanks again.

Comment: I could not get it work work.  I get NaN.  I am only using the Javascript from the documentation like above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="newtextbox required" digits="true" min="4" max="16">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the plugin. See https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/447 for a patch.